# String tokenizer for CPP String?

Tags: c++, string, tokenize

I want to use string Tokenizer for CPP string but all I could find was for Char*.
Is there anything similar for CPP string?

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx They are very efficient and somewhat elegant. The String Toolkit Library makes complex string processing in C++ simple and easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using strtok with a std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289347/using-strtok-with-a-stdstring)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you mean by "token"? If it's something separated by *any whitespace*, the string streams is what you want:

```
std::istringstream iss("blah wrxgl bxrcy") 
for(;;) {
  std::string token;
  if(!(iss>>token)) break;
  process(token);
}
if(!iss.eof()) report_error();
```

Alternatively, if your looking for a a certain single separating character, you can replace `iss>>token` with `std::getline(iss,token,sep_char)`.

If it's more than one character that can act as a separator (and if it's not whitespaces), a combinations of `std::string::find_first()` and `std::string::substr()` should do.

Comment: Is there any good reason for preferring `for(;;)` over `while(iss>>token)` (assuming `token` was declared before the loop)? In this example it would be one line shorter, and, in my opinion, at least not less readable.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: (I only now understood your comment. Well, at least I think I do...) I just happen to prefer a more local variable over the terseness of the `while` loop.

Comment: @sbi You could use a for-loop like this: `for (string token; iss >> token; ){...}` to get rid of the if-statement and still have a localized variable.

Comment: @erlc That seems indeed better than my solution. Good idea! (I would amend my answer, but that's a pain to do on the phone. Feel free to do it yourself, if you want.)

Answer (score 4):

You can do as said by chubsdad or use boost tokenizer : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm

Doing it by yourself is not so complicated if you're affraid by Boost.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/tokenizer/introduc.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check out STL algos like *find_first_of*, *find_first_not_of* and so on to create a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet I found somewhere (maybe even around here?):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while(std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    return split(s, delim, elems);
}
```