# How to use strtok() using a string argumnet instead of character array?

Tags: c++, strtok, token

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using strtok with a string argument (instead of char*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289347/using-strtok-with-a-string-argument-instead-of-char)

When using `strtok()` i do the following

```
char str[300];
while(infile) {
  infile.getline(str,300);
  char* token=strtok(str," ");
```

How can i use a string instead of the character array `char str[300];`

is there a way to use it to be like this,`string str;
    while(infile) {
      infile.getline(str,300);
      char* token=strtok(str," ");`

Comment: no i checked it before i ask its not the same

Comment: the strtok() function takes in a character array as an argument i want it to take a string as an argument instead of a character array

Comment: @Shadi: How is your question different?

Comment: @Shadi Well, you can't change the standard library!

Comment: i edited the question to help understand

Comment: Yes we understand the question, but you can't change the standard library. The other question, that this is a duplicate of, gives you many many good options.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, at least not without great care; `strtok()` modifies its argument, writing a `\0` into it after every recognized token, and generally behaves like a function that's poorly behaved even for C, much less C++.  My advice would be to look for a native C++ solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an `std::string`, you cannot, `strtok` only works with `char*`.

An easy solution could be that of `strdup` your `string.c_str`, and pass it to `strtok`.

Comment: I am not talking about the token char* ,, iam talking about the arguments the strtok takes in,the strtok() function takes in a character array as an argument i want it to take a string as an argument instead of a character array

Comment: @Shadi: you should write a wrapper for `strtok` which gets an `std::string`, gets the character array stored in it (using `c_str`), passes it to `strtok`, converts the result in an `std::string` and gives it back.

Answer (score -1):

```
string str;
while(infile)
{
    getline(infile, str);
    char* token=strtok(&str[0], " ");
}
```

Clean it ain't, but it will work.

EDIT: My mistake, this may not work in all circumstances.

Comment: why is this voted -1 will it work or not

Comment: Sorry, it might not. Although &str[0] does get you a pointer to a modifiable version of the string, it's not guaranteed to be null-terminated.