# error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using strtok with a std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289347/using-strtok-with-a-stdstring)

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s("hello hi here whola");
    string background;
    char *strval;

    char* tok = strtok_r(s.c_str()," ",&strval);
    while(tok !=NULL)
    {
    cout << tok <<"\n";
    if (tok == "&")
        background = tok;
    else
    {
        statements1;
        statement2.. ;
    }
    tok = strtok_r(NULL, " ",&strval);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
new.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
new.cpp:13:47: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/string.h:359:14: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strtok_r(char*, const char*, char**)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: why did you tag this C? Are you under the impression that C and C++ are the same language?

Comment: That is truly horrible. Pick a language first, I recommend C++.

Comment: Why do people tag it as c and C++ when they are different languages?

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289347/using-strtok-with-a-stdstring

Comment: Downvoting this because you don't like the code isn't right. It's a good, clear question with a short, self-contained, (almost-) compilable code snippet. Consider posting an answer instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 10):

The `s.c_str()` returns a pointer to the const char to prevent you from modifying the backing up memory. You need to make a writable copy of this constant string say with `strdup()` function as `strtok()` really modifies the string that you are scanning for tokens.

Comment: The problem lies in using c++ string class and char * type from C together.

Comment: @Andrej I am curious if the 'char *' type is forbidden in C++ :)

Comment: Well of course it is not, but mixing those types is the given case seems unnecessary and a little bit dangerous.

Comment: @Andrej I agree, but the question sounds as 'why it produces the error at compile time', not as 'please tell me how to write error-proof code in c++ using its 'native' API'

Comment: You are right once more but if some code compiles it does not automatically mean that is it good and can not produce and run-time errors.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` modifies its argument. This is not allowed with `string.c_str()` since it is a *const* char*

Also, even if it worked your `if( tok == "&" )` will not work since tok is a char*, not a string, and you will thus be doing pointer and not content comparisons.

You would need to use `strcmp()`

Since you are using string, why not go for broke and use other c++ constructs?

```
stringstream ss(s);
string tmp; 
while (ss >> buf) {
    if( buf == "&" ) background = buf; // one wonders why
    cout << buf << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mixing C++ `string`s and `cout`s with the C `strtok_r` function. It's not a good combination.

The immediate cause of your error is that `c_str()` returns a `const char *` while `strtok()` asks for a non-const `char *`. It wants to modify the string you pass as an argument, and you're not allowed to modify the string that `c_str()` returns.

If you want to do this C-style, then switch `s` to a `char[]`.

```
char s[] = "hello hi here whola";
int background = 0;
char *strval;

char* tok = strtok_r(s, " ", &strval);
while (tok != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", tok);

    if (strcmp(tok, "&") == 0)
        background = 1;
    else
    {
        statement1;
        statement2;
        ...
    }

    tok = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &strval);
}
```