# Convert string to constant char

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert my string into a const char that can be used with the strtok function. What am  I doing wrong?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char * pointer_char;
    int pos = 0;
    std::string str = "   Hello good sirtttttt..!.";
    int i = 0;
    int length = str.length();  
    const char * cstr = str.c_str();

    cout << "Testing string is " << str << endl << endl;
    pointer_char = strtok (str.c_str()," ,.;-!?@#$%^&");
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having ? Unexpected result, error message.. ?

Comment: Are you getting an error? I see that the problem is that `str.c_str()` returns a `const char *` whereas `strok` receives a non-`const` one, and situations like that typically emit a compiler-error. You should give us this information so that the problem can be deduced more seamlessly.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/289347/1472897

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `.c_str()` result with `strtok` directly.

`strtok` needs `char*` not a constant and it tries to change the passed string. Since your passed string comes from a `const char*` then it's not possible to change it. If you try to cast it to a non-const type before passing it to this function then *undefined behavior* will be invoked.

You need to make a copy and then pass that copy to `strtok`, for example:

```
char *c = strdup(str.c_str()); // It's not standard but simple to write
pointer_char = strtok(c," ,.;-!?@#$%^&");
free(c);
```

Try not to use `strtok` specially in C++ (you have many alternatives), it is not thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` doesn't take `const char *` as first parameter it takes a `char*`. The string has to be modifiable.

```
char *strtok (char *str, const char *delimiters);
```

`str`
C string to truncate.
Notice that this string is modified by being broken into smaller strings (tokens).
Alternativelly, a null pointer may be specified, in which case the function continues scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.