# split string on condition using strtok?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have array[2][3]= {e-> id = m,
                   m-> t|e|null};

I am trying to split the string in both ways: if it founds ' " " ' (empty space) it should split and if it founds "|"  then it also again splits. I know this is not correct but any one who can help me?

```
for i=0 t0 row 
   for j=0 to col
      c41= a[i][j].c_str();
      strcpy(pch55,c41);
      pch5=strtok(pch55,"|" || " "); // is it correct???
      for ( int u=0;pch5 != NULL;u++)
      {
          z33[u]= pch5;

          pch5 = strtok (NULL,"|" || " ");  //is it correct??

      }
```

Comment: What kind of C++ is this? That preamble looks like pseudo-code. Using `strtok` is also C, not C++.

Comment: @tadman: The entire C string library is available in C++.  So `strtok` is C++.

Comment: I caution you against using `strtok`, as it modifies your string.  If possible, switch over to `std::string` and use the `find*` methods.

Comment: i am trying when space or "|" comes it shd split the string so how should i do?

Comment: "Splitting" a string may also be known as creating a *substring* which is often abbreviated as `substr` (hint).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That would be C by definition, since it's the C library. That C and C++ are inter-operable is simply a feature. There's nothing in this question that is C++-specific.

Comment: `array[2][3]= {e-> id = m, m-> t|e|null};`? What even is that? `for i=0 t0 row` is invalid, as is `for j=0 to col`, at least in C++. Looks more like BASIC or something. `strcpy(...)` and following are not inside the loop like they're maybe supposed to be guessing by indentation - this isn't Python. None of the variables are declared, so their types are completely non-obvious. `strtok(pch55, "|" || " ")` is equivalent to `strtok(pch55, "|")` - the logical OR with space there is completely pointless. So much more...

Comment: @tadman:  Did you catch the statement `c41= a[i][j].c_str();` in the code?  My understanding is `.c_str()` is not a C language method, but usually the method invocation from `std::string`.

Comment: Good observation. That was lost in the rather disastrous formatting there. Found [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289347/using-strtok-with-a-stdstring) with some suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pch5=strtok(pch55,"| "); // notice the space at the end
```

on line 5, and

```
pch5=strtok(NULL, "| ");
```

on line 10.

The 2nd arg of strtok(3) is a collection of characters to use as delimiters, not a string delimiter.  And, the NULL tells it to continue from where it left off.

Comment: its not working remember my array has a[2][3]={e-> id = m, m-> t|e|null}; and i want to split when space or "|" comes.