# c++: parse a string that contains an expression "access to the multidimensinal array"

Tags: c++, string, parsing

How can one write a helper method that for a given string like `foo[0][1][2][3]` splits it into the array's name and collection (e.g. vector) of indices? In the example above it should produce `foo` and `0, 1, 2, 3` respectively.

The format of a string is always like `name[index_0][index_1]....[index_n]`.
The number of indices (`n`) is not known in advance. All should be numbers. For simplicity, no spaces are allowed in a string. The name of an array (`name`) can be arbitrary. The helper function throws in case the string is not according to the specified format.

Performance is not an issue here. I'm looking for the most elegant/short solution.

**UPDATE**

Well, regular expressions were suggested in the very first comment. I was new to the area and went through the hassle of getting it done in C++. Please, feel free to simplify it. In the meantime, two non-regular expressions based solutions were proposed by @MartinYork and @Frodyne. At a first glance, regular expressions didn't bring anything fascinating here. The solution does not seem to be much shorter or much more elegant in my mind.

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<int>> helper(std::string str) {
  // used to validate that the incoming string is in format
  // array[0][1][2]
  const std::regex rx_validate{
      "([[:alnum:]]+)((?:\\[[[:digit:]]+\\])+)$"};

  std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> match_results;
  std::regex_search(str, match_results, rx_validate);

  // regex_search array[0][1][2] gives
  // match_results[0]: array[0][1][2]
  // match_results[1]: array
  // match_results[2]: [0][1][2]
  if (match_results.size() == 3) {
    std::vector<int> indices;

    // used to extract indices, it is guaranteed that
    // numbers are between brackets, no extra checks
    // needed
    const std::regex rx_index{"[0-9]+"};
    const std::string match{match_results[2]};
    auto it = std::sregex_iterator(match.begin(), match.end(), rx_index);
    for (; it != std::sregex_iterator(); ++it)
      indices.push_back(std::stoi((*it).str()));

    return std::make_tuple(match_results[1], indices);
  } else {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid format (" + str + ")");
  }
}

int main() {
  const std::string str{"a[0][1][2][3][4][5]"};
  const auto tuple = helper(str);

  std::cout << "Name: " << std::get<0>(tuple) << std::endl;
  for (int index: std::get<1>(tuple))
    std::cout << index << std::endl;
}
```

**UPDATE2**

@rici suggested a modification of an algorithm that used regular expressions. It's a bit shorter and more concise.

I was really interested in comparing those algorithms in terms of performance.

Not going to advocate the numbers :-) Everybody should decide on their own.

The below program compiled as `g++ -std=c++11 -Ofast` and running on `i7-8550U` gives:

```
Regex measurements...
min/max/avg 955/154859/1072.88
Stream measurements...
min/max/avg 722/41252/800.402
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <tuple>

#include <time.h>

inline uint64_t Timestamp() {
  timespec time_now;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_now);
  return static_cast<uint64_t>(time_now.tv_sec) * 1000000000ULL + time_now.tv_nsec;
}

std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<int>> helper_stream(std::string const& info)
{
    std::stringstream is(info);
    std::string         name;
    std::vector<int>    index;

    if (std::getline(is, name, '[')) {
        is.putback('[');
        name.erase(std::remove(std::begin(name), std::end(name), ' '), std::end(name));

        int   value;
        char  b1;
        char  b2;
        while(is >> b1 >> value >> b2 && b1 == '[' && b2 == ']') {
            index.push_back(value);
        }
    }
    return std::make_tuple(name, index);
}

std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<int>> helper_regex(std::string str) {
    static const std::regex strip_prefix{"^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*"};
    static const std::regex index{"\\[([[:digit:]]+)\\]|."};
    std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> match;
    if (std::regex_search(str, match, strip_prefix)) {
        auto e = match[0].second;
        std::vector<int> indices;
        for (auto it = std::sregex_iterator(e, str.end(), index), lim = std::sregex_iterator(); it != lim; ++it) {
            if ((*it)[1].matched)
                indices.push_back(std::stoi((*it)[1]));
            else throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid format");
        }
        return std::make_tuple(std::string(str.cbegin(), e), indices);
    }
    else
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid format (" + str + ")");
}

std::string make_str(int n) {
  std::string str{"array"};

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    str += "[";
    str += std::to_string(std::rand());
    str += "]";
  }

  return str;
}

template <typename F>
void measurements(F f) {
  constexpr int kNumRounds = 1000000;
  constexpr int kLength = 3;

  std::vector<uint64_t> time_diffs(kNumRounds);

  for (int i = 0; i < kNumRounds; ++i) {
    const std::string str{make_str(kLength)};

    const auto before = Timestamp();
    f(str);
    const auto after = Timestamp();

    time_diffs[i] = after - before;
  }

  uint64_t min{std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()};
  uint64_t max{std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::min()};
  uint64_t sum{0};

  for (int i = 0; i < kNumRounds; ++i) {
    const auto time_diff = time_diffs[i];

    if (time_diff < min)
      min = time_diff;

    if (time_diff > max)
      max = time_diff;

    sum += time_diff;
  }

  std::cout << "min/max/avg " << min << "/" << max << "/" << static_cast<double>(sum) / kNumRounds << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Regex measurements..." << std::endl;
  measurements(helper_regex);

  std::cout << "Stream measurements..." << std::endl;
  measurements(helper_stream);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: [Now they have two problems!](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems):-)

Comment: Could you define the format of the string more exactly. Will it always have `foo`? will it always have four index's? Will the indexes always be integers? Are spaces allowed/required in any parts of the string? What are the types and formats of the output?

Comment: @MartinYork, thank you for your comment. I'll update the original post.

Comment: answers in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289347/using-strtok-with-a-stdstring)  might give you some idea.

Comment: Well, regular expressions were suggested in the very first comment. I was new to the area and went through the hassle of getting it done in C++. I'll update the original post and include my solution. Please, feel free to simplify it. In the meantime, two non-regular expressions based solutions were proposed by @MartinYork and @ Frodyne. At a first glance, regular expressions didn't bring anything fascinating here. The solution does not seem to be much shorter or much more elegant in my mind.

Comment: @TruLa: I think the regex solution can be somewhat more elegant or at least shorter. For example, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c6aedb1ecec2e36. Note that it is simple to adapt the regex solution to, for example, accept whitespace inside the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the few times I would advocate falling back to the C parsing functions. Though it could be done by regular expression this seems a bit heavy weight for something so trivial.

I would use the C function `sscanf()`

```
std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<int>> ck1(std::string const& info)
{

    int                 functionStartSize = 0;
    int                 functionNameSize = 0;
    char                check = 'X';
    std::vector<int>   index;

    if (std::sscanf(info.data(), " %n%*[^\[]%n%c", &functionStartSize, &functionNameSize, &check) == 1 && check == '[') {

        // Format String: " %n%*[^\[]%n%c"
        // ' ':        Ignore all leading space.
        // %n:         Save number of characters of space we dropped.
        // %*[^\[]:    Lets split this up
        //             %*      scan but don't save to a variable.
        //             [..]    Only the letters we find inside the brackets.
        //             ^\]     Everything except ]
        // %n:         Save the number of characters we have used to here.
        // %c:         A character This should now be a '['
        // We have correctly found the beginning and end of the name.

        int size;
        int value;
        int offset = functionNameSize;
        while(std::sscanf(info.data() + offset, "[%d%c%n", &value, &check, &size) == 2 && check == ']') {
            // We have found another index
            index.push_back(value);
            offset += size;
        }
    }
    return std::make_tuple(info.substr(functionStartSize, (functionNameSize-functionStartSize), index);
}
```

When I was first writing the above code I assumed that `%n` would count just like any other parameter. Unfortunately it does not count towards the return value. This made the check for each index slightly more obscure and thus I am not thinking it is better to use the stream one below.

The streams don't do that bad:
A full copy of the string into the string stream. But for small strings not a big issue.

```
std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<int>> ck2(std::string const& info)
{
    std::stringstream is(info);
    std::string         name;
    std::vector<int>    index;

    if (std::getline(is, name, '[')) {
        is.putback('[');
        name.erase(std::remove(std::begin(name), std::end(name), ' '), std::end(name));

        int   value;
        char  b1;
        char  b2;
        while(is >> b1 >> value >> b2 && b1 == '[' && b2 == ']') {
            index.push_back(value);
        }
    }
    return std::make_tuple(name, index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my original post. I agree with you. I cannot see benefits in using regular expressions to solve this problem.

Comment: That's `std::sscanf()`, assuming you're including the C++ header `<cstdio>`. The compatibility header `<stdio.h>`, isn't recommended for new code.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes. Is there a flag to check that?

Comment: There's [no way](//stackoverflow.com/q/44694574) to catch that error using GCC. The only [useful suggestion](//stackoverflow.com/q/44694574#comment79116631_44694574) was to build with Oracle's Studio compiler on Solaris.  (Sadly, I no longer have any Solaris boxes, and I never had that compiler...)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is fairly similar to the one by Martin York, but I used stl instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<int>> getNameIndices(std::string s)
{
    std::vector<int> indices;

    // The name must end at the first '['
    size_t pos = s.find("[");
    // If we can't find that, then it isn't a valid string - return empty
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        return std::make_tuple("", indices);

    // Get the name and remove it from the string
    std::string name = s.substr(0, pos);
    s.erase(0, pos + 1);

    size_t begin = 0;
    // Keep looping as long as we can find the start of a new index
    while ((pos = s.find("]")) != std::string::npos)
    {
        // Begin is the position of the '[', pos is the ']': Get the text between them
        std::string tmp = s.substr(begin, pos - begin);
        indices.push_back(stoi(tmp));
        // Remove the characters that were matched, and update 'begin'
        s.erase(0, pos + 1);
        begin = s.find("[") + 1;
    }

    // Return the name and indices in a vector
    return std::make_tuple(name, indices);
}

void main()
{
    std::string s = "foo[500][12][2][13]";

    auto b = getNameIndices(s);

    std::cout << "Name: " << std::get<0>(b) << std::endl;
    for (int i : std::get<1>(b))
    {
        std::cout << "\t" << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use the STL you should be using `std::stringstream` and `operator >>` and `std::getline()` to extract the parts.

Comment: @MartinYork Having seen your STL solution, I agree: That way looks much cleaner and better.